# Game theory of writing multiple choice tests

Tags: pr.probability, game-theory, applied-mathematics

Here is a model which seems pretty close to my experience of writing multiple choice tests.

Let's view the answer $t$ to each question as a binary string in $S:=\{ 0,1 \}^k$, all equally likely. The scantron sheet offers $a$ answers per question, so the instructor must present the student with an $a$-element set $C$ of choices, one of which must be the true answer $t$. The student tries to solve the problem on his or her own, obtaining a string $s \in S$; each of the bits of $s$ has probability $p>1/2$ of matching the corresponding bit of $t$ and probability $1-p$ of being flipped. The student must then, as a function of $C$ and $s$, choose one of the elements of $C$.

A pure strategy for the instructor is a function from $S$ to $a$-element subsets of $S$, turning the true answer $t$ into the list of choices $C$. A mixed strategy for the instructor is a probability distribution on pure strategies.

The student knows the instructor's mixed strategy (the instructor has written many exams, which are now in the basements of fraternities) and know his probability of error $p$ (the student has taken practice exams). Therefore, upon seeing $C$ and computing $s$, the student performs a quick maximum likelihood analysis and returns the element of $C$ most likely to have lead to the pair $(C,s)$.

The instructor wants to minimize both Type I errors (students who have $s\neq t$ but answer correctly) and Type II errors (students who have $s =t$ but answer incorrectly). For concreteness sake, let's say the instructor wants to minimize the sum of these, although other weightings are certainly reasonable.

> How well can the instructor do?

Comment: Perhaps "the student tries to solve the problem on his or her own"?

Comment: My plan was to write the student as male and the instructor as female, but it looks like the final draft left no pronouns referring to the instructor.  Sure, I'll make your edit, that's easier than figuring out how to put some pronouns back.

Comment: And then from this MO question out pours the optimal strategy when guessing on a scantron!...

I'm more interested in the student's strategy...

Comment: Maybe I'm misreading you, but (as I read it) you wrote $t$ as the final list of $k$ answers given by the student, describing if they are right and wrong--isn't this sort of the wrong way of modeling it? Shouldn't you take the larger space of $S= \{1,2,3,...,a\}^k$ and assign a value $T \in S$ as the perfect score, and model the probability and likelihood off this? 
The more I read this question the more I feel it needs complexification and a more real world feel for the sheer cleverness of it.

Comment: @james.nixon $t$ is the answer to a single question, modeled as a binary string. For example, the bits of this string could represent "Is the matrix $2 \times 3$ or $3 \times 2$? Did I get the sign right? Do I invert $AA^T$ or $A^T A$? ..." I feel that the typical question has about 4 independent binary errors. If my scantron had 16 slots, I would just give all options, but it has 5. The thing the SATs tend to do is to give the right answer and everything at Hamming distance one from it, but this means the smart test taker can identify the answer without knowing anything about the question.

Comment: As an example:  If the instructor offers the correct answer and a uniformly random sample of other answers, and the student chooses randomly among answers with the most bits matching their guess (I'm not sure if this is the maximum likelihood approach), with a=3, k=3, q=1-p, then errors are all type I and occur with probability (32ppq+4pqq)/21.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer Oh okay, I did misread you.